# Creating a slug in the URL when using PHP String to pull data

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This may be something simple for most PHP coders, however, I have never had to do this before. I am using Wordpress website with a Page Template. On this page is a page I created to Query results by User_id, then displaying the users profile information. What I am trying to achieve is the following:

Page #1 
Lawyers Directory > Has Multiple Lawyers being pulled from Database

Action: 
Click Link 
(Example Link: http://example.com/lawyer-profile?user_id=9)
*the number 9 is the dynamic number

Page #2 
Lawyer Profile > Has Profile Info of Lawyer

PROBLEM
How do I change this URL 
http://example.com/lawyer-profile?user_id=9

TO

http://example.com/lawyer-profile/john-doe/

But still pull the data by using the User_id?

Any help would be appreciated!

---

UPDATE:
I found this on wordpress's website and I modified it to reflect what I would need it to do but it doesn't work. It redirects to the lawyer-directory page which is page_id 189 but still shows the query strings in the URL.

Here is the url i am using:
http://example.com/index.php?page_id=189&userid=195&fullname=jack-bowers

and it should look like this:
http://example.com/lawyer-directory/jack-bowers/

any suggestions?

```
 function custom_rewrite_tag() {
   add_rewrite_tag('%userid%', '([^&]+)');
   add_rewrite_tag('%fullname%', '([^&]+)');
 }
 add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

 function custom_rewrite_rule() {
     add_rewrite_rule('^lawyer-directory/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=189&userid=$matches[1]&fullname=$matches[2]','top');
 }
 add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Comment: _“But still pull the data by using the User_id?”_ – if you are not _passing_ the id as a parameter in your URL, then you can not “pull the data” by that id, because you do not _have_ the id in your script … that should be pretty obvious. Either pass the id as well (many systems use something like `/lawyer-profile/9/john-doe/`, where only the `9` has actual meaning and the rest doesn’t matter) – or rewrite your script to select the data by the value that _does_ get passed instead, `john-doe`. For that to properly work, the value should be unique within your data set of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Wordpress, take a look at [add_rewrite_rule()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). Along with add_rewrite_tag, this will allow you to handle that.

What you can do is define a rewrite tag for user_id, and a rewrite rule to map your pattern to the single page that handles it. You can then get the value  using query_vars eg.

```
$wp_query->query_vars['user_id']
```

So this would return eg. john-doe. On your database you would have an index for the lawyer's permalink which you can then look up to find their id/record.

It's a bit confusing at first, but there is a decent example in the doc linked above.

Comment: I posted an update with a code snippet. Can you take a look at it for me and tell me why it isn't working? It will go to the correct page, but doesn't show the url like it's suppose to.